# Distribute weight along the edges of a tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, time-complexity, computer-science

```
A tree with N nodes and N-1 Bidirectional edges, and given an integer S.

Now, you have to assign the weights to the edges of this tree such that: 
    1. the sum of the weights of all the edges is equal to S 
    2. for every possible diameter of the tree, the maximum weight over all the edges covered by its paths is the minimum possible.

Output this minimum possible edge weight.
The diameter of a tree is the number of nodes on the longest path between two leaves in the tree

Constraints
1 <= T <= 10
1 <= N <= 2*10^3
1 <= u,v <= N
1 <= S <= 10^9

Input Format 
The first line of the input contains an Integer T, the total number of test cases.

The first line of each test case contains two space separated integers N and
S,the number of nodes in a tree and the integer S as mentioned in the problem statement.

Then the N-1 lines follow, each containing two space-separated integers u
and v representing that there is a bidirectional edge between the nodes u and v.
```

[image: sample test cases]

[image: Explanation]

I am not able to formulate a strategy to distribute weight to all the edges in the asked manner. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: The answer given for example 1 appears to be incorrect according to the problem description, so it's hard to know what you're asking.

Comment: @MattTimmermans answer is correct as for example 1 there exist 6 diameters(4-> 7, 4-> 8, 5-> 7, 5-> 8, 6-> 7, 6-> 8) that are of equal length and among them the diameter with lowest over-all edge weight is 4->8 and according to problem we has to return edge with maximum weight from the diameter with lowest over-all edge weight. So the edge with maximum weight in 4->8 is 3 and hence answer is 3. What i am asking is for a way using which i will distribute weight over edges in tree keeping in mind the 2 conditions.

Comment: Oh, I see... "maximum weight over all the edges covered" is not a sum.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases:

1. If every edge participates in at least one diameter, then the best you can do is to divide `S` as evenly as possible among the `N` - 1 edges. Thus, the answer is `⌈S/(N-1)⌉`. This is the case for your test #1.
2. If there exists at least one edge that doesn't participate in any diameter, then you can distribute all of `S` there and the answer is 0. This is the case for the edge 1-4 in your test #2.

So we've reduced the problem to determining all the edges that do not belong to any diameter. There is a well-written answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54046436/6022817).